# Buscar int menor en un archivo en C recursivo

Tags: c

me piden que busque de manera **recursiva** el menor entero en un archivo de enteros. El archivo ya lo tengo creado y tengo la funcion "iterativa" para buscar el menor, pero no se me ocurre como hacerla de manera recursiva. Les dejo mi codigo para que vean como busco el menor

```
int buscaMenor(){
    int menor=0;
    int dato=0;
    FILE * pArchEnteros = fopen(AR_NUMEROS,"rb");
    if(pArchEnteros){
        dato = fread(&dato,sizeof(int),1,pArchEnteros);
        while(fread(&menor,sizeof(int),1,pArchEnteros) > 0){
            if(menor < dato){
                dato = menor;
            }
        }
        fclose(pArchEnteros);
    }
    return dato;
}
```

Lo que hace esta funcion es abrir el archivo, verificar si se abrio correctamente con el if(pArchEnteros). Luego hace la lectura mientras que el retorno del *fread* sea mayor a 0 y en las lecturas va comparando los datos almacenando el menor en dato.

Answer (score 1):

No he utilizado `C` jamas, pero la recursividad del siguiente `while`:

```
while(fread(&menor,sizeof(int),1,pArchEnteros) > 0){
        if(menor < dato){
            dato = menor;
        }
}
```

Quedaría mas o menos así:

```
int recursividadMenor(FILE &pArchEnteros, int &menor, int dato){
    if(! fread(menor,sizeof(int),1,pArchEnteros) )
        return dato;
    if(menor<dato)
        return recursividadMenor(pArchEnteros,menor,menor)
    return recursividadMenor(pArchEnteros,menor,dato)
}
```

A partir de este código podrías adaptarlo para obtener la solucion.